# Ubuntu 20.04 only printing in monochrome on Xerox phaser 6130N after upgrade from 18.04

Tags: printing

My Xerox Phaser 6130N printer worked perfectly well with 18.04. Then I updated to 20.04 and thought everything was fine until I went to print something in colour. No luck. Every print comes out in monochrome now, and I can find nothing to fix it.

Interestingly if I follow this path:

```
Launch the Settings app
click on Printers | Additional Printer Settings
double click on printer icon for the Xerox printer
click on Job Options
scroll to the bottom
```

There I find the section titled "Other Options (Advanced)" and in there is an option named print-color-mode and it is set to "monochrome". That option has a pulldown that (in theory) should let me choose something other than monochrome, but when I click on the down arrow to see the choices, there is only one choice present, and it is monochrome.

I've printed successfully on this printer for many years, with various versions of Ubuntu. What the heck is going on here to break colour printing?

Help?

--- edited on Nov 30 to provide additional information ---

Thank you for the response. I will do my best to supply what you need.

However, this is a network attached printer, not directly connected to the machine. I think that might matter, and I did not make it obvious in my first post. The N on the printer model number indicates it's network attached, but that is pretty obscure, sorry.

Anyway...

```
$ lpstat -a
Xerox accepting requests since Sun 29 Nov 2020 01:18:57 PM PST
```

So I think the queue name is Xerox.

And your first lpoptions command:

```
$ lpoptions -p Xerox -l
PageSize/Page Size: Custom.WIDTHxHEIGHT *Letter A4 11x17 A3 A5 B5 Env10 EnvC5 EnvDL EnvISOB5 EnvMonarch Executive Legal
Duplex/Double-Sided Printing: DuplexNoTumble DuplexTumble *None
Resolution/Resolution: 150x150dpi 300x300dpi *600x600dpi 1200x1200dpi
```

And the contents of the line you wanted from Xerox.ppd:

```
$ sudo grep '*NickName' /etc/cups/ppd/Xerox.ppd 
*NickName:      "Xerox Phaser 6130N Foomatic/Postscript"
```

(The sudo wasn't actually needed there. My user appears to be a member of group lp for some reason, and the file is readable by anyone in that group.)

The alternative you provided didn't produce any output:

```
$ lpoptions -p Xerox | grep Model
$
```

But I think that is because "Model" is not capitalized in the output. And in any case lpoptions seems to be outputting everything in one long string in any case, so the grep would not eliminate anything. Here is the only item containing the string "model" in the output:

```
printer-make-and-model='Xerox Phaser 6130N Foomatic/Postscript'
```

and here is the full output of the command without the grep:

```
$ lpoptions -p Xerox
copies=1 device-uri=dnssd://Xerox%20Phaser%206130N%20(a6%3Aa3%3A2d)._pdl-datastream._tcp.local/ finishings=3 job-cancel-after=10800 job-hold-until=no-hold job-priority=50 job-sheets=none,none marker-change-time=1606684737 marker-colors=#00FFFF,#FF00FF,#FFFF00,#000000,none,none marker-levels=-1,-1,-1,-1,80,100 marker-names='Cyan\ Toner\ Cartridge,\ Phaser\ 6130N,Magenta\ Toner\ Cartridge,\ Phaser\ 6130N,Yellow\ Toner\ Cartridge,\ Phaser\ 6130N,Black\ Toner\ Cartridge,\ Phaser\ 6130N,Imaging\ Unit,Fuser,\ Phaser\ 6130' marker-types=toner,toner,toner,toner,opc,fuser number-up=1 printer-commands=AutoConfigure,Clean,PrintSelfTestPage printer-info='Xerox Xerox Phaser 6130N' printer-is-accepting-jobs=true printer-is-shared=true printer-is-temporary=false printer-location='Anne's Office' printer-make-and-model='Xerox Phaser 6130N Foomatic/Postscript' printer-state=3 printer-state-change-time=1606684737 printer-state-reasons=none printer-type=8564756 printer-uri-supported=ipp://localhost/printers/Xerox
```

But that is so long it is very difficult to read. Here I have captured the output and put each entry (separated by unescaped spaces originally) on a separate line:

```
copies=1
device-uri=dnssd://Xerox%20Phaser%206130N%20(a6%3Aa3%3A2d)._pdl-datastream._tcp.local/
finishings=3
job-cancel-after=10800
job-hold-until=no-hold
job-priority=50
job-sheets=none,none
marker-change-time=1606684737
marker-colors=#00FFFF,#FF00FF,#FFFF00,#000000,none,none
marker-levels=-1,-1,-1,-1,80,100
marker-names='Cyan\ Toner\ Cartridge,\ Phaser\ 6130N,Magenta\ Toner\ Cartridge,\ Phaser\ 6130N,Yellow\ Toner\ Cartridge,\ Phaser\ 6130N,Black\ Toner\ Cartridge,\ Phaser\ 6130N,Imaging\ Unit,Fuser,\ Phaser\ 6130'
marker-types=toner,toner,toner,toner,opc,fuser number-up=1
printer-commands=AutoConfigure,Clean,PrintSelfTestPage
printer-info='Xerox Xerox Phaser 6130N'
printer-is-accepting-jobs=true
printer-is-shared=true
printer-is-temporary=false
printer-location='Anne's Office'
printer-make-and-model='Xerox Phaser 6130N Foomatic/Postscript'
printer-state=3
printer-state-change-time=1606684737
printer-state-reasons=none
printer-type=8564756
printer-uri-supported=ipp://localhost/printers/Xerox
```

I hope that helps.

To get my printing done (I was in a time crunch) I had to get out an ancient Windows laptop and print from there. It printed in colour just fine, so I know the issue is not with the printer.

Finally, if it matters, sending a test print by clicking on "Print Test Page" in the printer properties dialog box also results in a monochrome print, even though the contents clearly show it should be printing in colour. It has graphic elements clearly intended to show separate prints of the various printer cartridges - Cyan, Magenta, Red, Green, and Black, but they all come out various shades of gray.

Also, my wife's Ubuntu machine was also recently upgraded to 20.04 and it has exactly the same problem: it prints only in black & white when it printed in colour before.

I hope this helps! I'd sure like to print in colour without having to resort to Windows.

Thanks.

Comment: Your print queue has a name. Provide the output of `lpoptions -p PRINT_Q_NAME -l`. Also give `sudo grep *NickName /etc/cups/ppd/PRINT_Q_NAME.ppd`.

Comment: The output of `lpoptions -p PRINT_Q_NAME -l | grep Model` would be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you @brian_p. I think I have added everything you asked about to the question above.

Comment: You are using the Xerox Phaser 6130N Foomatic/Postscript driver. If that driver is what you used successfully before your upgrade, it looks like a bug in foomatic. There is a gutenprint driver for your device. I do not know whether it makes any difference.

Comment: Do you get any output with `avahi-browse -rt _ipp._tcp`?

Comment: Thanks again @brian_p. I get nothing from the avahi-browse command you ask about. Nothing at all. As for the driver, I did nothing to change the driver during or after the upgrade. And I cannot even recall the history under 18.04, but printing in colour worked before the upgrade just fine. I am no expert, but I will dig around for the gutenprint driver and see if I can get it to work. How would I report the issue in foomatic, though?

Comment: See below. This has been resolved by installing a new PPD driver from Xerox.

Answer (score 1):

I run Mint and Ubuntu.  I came across this issue.
Mint 20.1 is pretty simular to 20.04

[link to drivers](https://download.support.xerox.com/pub/drivers/DocuColor_2006/drivers/unix/en/LinuxCupsPrinterPkg.tar.gz)

Pick the xrx6130n.ppd driver out of this package.
in printers, right click properties, click  make and model and "pick a ppd file"

For whatever reason on my Mint 20.1 computer, it would always freeze, saying "searching for drivers...
I eventually got a workaround by creating a new printer, selecting Generic-CUPS-BRF, then picking the PPD file out of the archive., Then I went back through the settings, changing the device uri setting from generic to the network socket where my printer is (im using 192.168.1.45 port 9100, yours will depend on your network and printer settings)

Mint 20.1 and ubuntu 18.04 have the same base driver in there packages, I dont understand why it works in color on 18.04 and not Mint 20.1....
They both even have the "monochrome" option as the only selection!!

the versions of cups im using are
2.3.1 -> Mint 20.1
2.2.6 -> ubuntu 18.04

Maybe some one might be able to determine what the issue is

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was it, John. You gave me the path to fix this.  Using your suggestion, I downloaded the driver package directly from the Xerox website. Inside there I found a Readme.txt file that explains how to get at CUPS from a web browser, and I was able to modify my existing printer definition to use the new PPD file. Now it prints in colour the way it should. Thank you!